# What does caching or not-Caching mean when talking about URL parameters (Matrix, Request or Path)

Tags: http, jakarta-ee

I read in several posts as I'm learning about http requests about the term "Caching" I know it means faster access but how and where ?

1. Matrix Params are cached, Pattern: http://some.where/thing;paramA=1;paramB=6542
2. Request/Query Params aren't cached, Pattern:  http://some.where/thing?paramA=1&paramB=6542
3. Path Params are cached, Pattern:  http://www.rest.services.com/item/b

So what does caching mean in this scope? I googled but no luck.

And Are there any other URL patterns ?

Ref: 1,2 From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048121/url-matrix-parameters-vs-request-parameters) and 3 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198492/rest-standard-path-parameters-or-request-parameters)

Comment: @julianReschke why then in the refs they say Num 2 is not ?

Comment: Ismail: there is a difference between "is cacheable" and "always gets cached".

Comment: @JulianReschke thanks for being precise, so can you help me understand what caching actually is ?

Comment: Ismail: see http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: Thanks @JulianReschke that should be the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these *can* be cached.

You may want to read

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/