# Use @RequestParam or @PathVariable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I' m developing a REST WebApp with spring framework, now i'd like to know the best practice to receive data. It s best to retrieve them with `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable`?Obviously i'm interested in receiving simple data like an `userid` or an `username`.
Using an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String GetData(@RequestParam(value = "memberId", required = true) Integer memberId){
  //return data for user with Id = memberid;
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getdata/{memberid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String GetData(@pathvariable int memberid){
  //return data for user with Id = memberid;
}
```

I'm interested about REST web services

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4028874/2504224, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198492/rest-standard-path-parameters-or-request-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest convention is to use uri variables :

```
get http://stackoverflow.com/users/3630157
```

Comment: This is what i was searching for, i forgot to say i was talking about rest web services

Answer (score 0):

@PathVarible is used in RESTful web service. Learn what is [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) . And the method name should start with lower case.

Comment: Yeah i forgot to say it was for RESTful web service

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of data you want to receive in the Controller.

You can use `@PathVariable` to get information from the uri.

Url:

```
exampleUrl/Application/example/someData
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="example/{someData}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Controller(@PathVariable("someData") String someData){        
  ...
}
```

And you can use @RequestParam to get a parameter from the url.

Url:

```
exampleUrl/Application/example/someData?parameter1=hello
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "example/someData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Controller(@RequestParam(value = "parameter1", required = false) String parameter1){        
          ...
        }
```

So there is no "better" way, it depends on how you want to handle your request and what kind of information you need.

Comment: But if i the information is the same, like in the example..I thought there was a convention or a best-practice to follow...

Answer (score 0):

Create a model map and add those parameter name/value pairs to it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/student/{username}/", method=RequestMethod.GET)

public String adminStudent(@PathVariable String username, @RequestParam String studentid, Model model)
{
    model.put("username", username);
    model.put("studentid", studentid);
    return "student";
}
```