# Error no mapping found for HTTP request with uri in my console

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to spring i am making a small project with using spring.I am getting error in my while running the project.Below is my controller, rest-servlet-xml and web.xml.I am not able to find what kind of error.I am using JBOSS6 INSIDE MY ECLIPSE

```
package com.webService.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service/greeting")
public class SpringServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getGreeting(@PathVariable String name) {
        String result="Hello "+name;        
        return result;
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.webService.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringServiceSample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you post your application context? Check: http://www.dineshonjava.com/2014/02/restcontroller-in-spring-40-framework.html

Comment: What is that i have not used that i have made this simple project as per the steps given in the internet.It was not mentioned there anything

Comment: Please check the link provided and also read: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Dear Partick, i have checked everything it is same like me but i am not to find out the error while running inside my eclipse it is working fine but while running with jboss6 it is giving me such error

Comment: I see, there are any logs in the server to share? Which server are you using inside eclipse?

Comment: 00:22:10,260 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/SpringWebService]] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring4'
00:22:10,401 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final
00:22:10,414 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
00:22:36,978 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWebService] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring4'

Comment: How are you accessing the service? It should be like: http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceSample/service/greeting/PatrickLC

Comment: 00:27:26,694 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWebService/service/greeting] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring4'

Comment: Yes in the same way...  http://localhost:8080/SpringWebService?service/greeting?name=suraj

Comment: Sorry, are you sure? I see question marks and you are trying to use querystring, again, please check with this exactly: http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceSample/service/greeting/PatrickLC

Comment: Hi sorry your link is working.But what is the problem in my link.http://localhost:8080/SpringWebService/service/greeting?name=suraj

Comment: what is the difference between http://localhost:8080/SpringWebService/service/greeting?name=PatrickLC  OR .localhost:8080/SpringWebService/service/greeting?name=suraj

Comment: Great news, please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to access the rest service this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringWebService/service/greeting?name=PatrickLC
```

But you have to access your defined rest service this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringWebService/service/greeting/PatrickLC
```

Why?
You have to take a look at the difference between a path variable (@PathVariable) and using a parameter in query string (@RequestParam). Check this questions:

- [@RequestParam vs @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715811/requestparam-vs-pathvariable)
- [Rest Standard: Path parameters or Request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198492/rest-standard-path-parameters-or-request-parameters)

Since you are working with REST, i really recommend you reading this: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/emag-rest