# Azure Function: Problem with query parameter in a custome HTTP rout

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function(V3) and I want to set a customer HTTP rout. I ended up with something like this:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(GetSomething))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",
            Route = "api/v1/a/b/{bName}/{locationList}?name={name?}&fromDate={fromDate?}&toDate={toDate?}")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, 
        string bName, string locationList, string name, string fromDate, string toDate)
    {
           //body
    }
```

I want to make those values after the `{locationList}` optional and give more flexibility for using that URL. However, the rout is not acceptable by the WebJob and the reason is the question mark '?' after `{locationList}`

```
"api/v1/a/b/{bName}/{locationList}?name={name?}&fromDate={fromDate?}&toDate={toDate?}"
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54644234/2688419). I am not following the answer. Does anyone have a better solution or at least an example of this part

> If it's the reason why you want to put query parameter in route, I would suggest you add IDictionary query in method signature and use query["manufacturer"] to access the parameter in function code. But honestly it's almost the same as request.Query["manufacturer"].

Comment: Don't know if this can be helpful (or it works): try setting ...`, string name = null, string fromDate = null, string toDate = null` in your signature.

Comment: @Emanuele does not work!

Comment: why do you need to include the query params at all in your route? if they are optional anyway, you can just read them in the function body from the `req` object

Comment: @silent this exactly what I asked myself. so I ended up moving that to the body