# FromQuery support in Azure Functions v3

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to use `[FromQuery]` with Azure Function v3 but I am getting the following error:

> Cannot bind parameter 'search' to type String.

For the following method:

```cs
[FunctionName("GetObjects")]
public ActionResult<IActionResult> QueryObjects(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "GET", Route = "objects")]
    HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log,
    [FromQuery] string search = null)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Is `[FromQuery]` not supported?

Should I use `req.Query["search"]` to get the query parameter?

From `functions.desp.json`

Related to binding

```json
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/3.1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "3.1.2"
    },
    "runtime": {
        "lib/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll": {
        "assemblyVersion": "3.1.1.0",
        "fileVersion": "3.100.119.61404"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: you can use, can you show the function.json

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan I am running this locally I haven´t published the function yet.

Comment: post your function.json file

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan I appreciate your help. I have the function.deps.json file but it contains alot of information I am not willing to share I would prefer if you could tell me what you are looking for in the file and I will have a look. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the bindings part of it?

Comment: hi, @Sajeetharan the only thing I found related to binding is in the updated question above. But as BowmanZhu states in his answer below, this is probably not supported although it would be nice to have feature.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: No I dont think this is supported so I am currently using req.Query["search"]

Comment: @doorman Hi, if my answer answers your question, can you mark it as the answer to end the question? :)

Comment: **See Also**: [How to get the GET Query Parameters in a simple way on Azure Functions C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49833056/1366033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you face now:

[image]

Method signatures developed by the azure function C # class library can include these:

> ILogger or TraceWriter for logging (v1 version only)
>
> A CancellationToken parameter for graceful shutdown
>
> Mark input and output bindings by using attribute decoration
>
> Binding expressions parameters to get trigger metadata

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings), it seems that it is not supported. You can create your custom binding like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Creating-custom-input-and-output-bindings), and dont forget to register it in the startup.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to bind it directly, it's not possible. So you could try to change your route like `Function1/name={name}&research={research}` then bind it to string parameter.

Below is my test code:

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route="Function1/name={name}&research={research}")] HttpRequest req,
    String name,
    String research,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    log.LogInformation(research);
    
    string responseMessage = $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

[image: screenshot]