# Sending variable Client Side (JS Ajax) to Server Side (Python Django)

Tags: django, python-3.x, ajax

I am using Python 3.7.4 with Django 3.0.3 and I have a script Ajax in javascript run in the front end app. When the user click in link, a variable must to be sending to back end python. See the exemple

**Javascript**

```
$('.likebutton').click(function() {
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        // url: "/likePost",
        url: "/likePost/" + catid,
        /* data: {
            post_id: catid
        },
        */   
        success: function(data) {
            $('#like' + catid).remove();
            $('#message').text(data);
        }
    })
});
```

**urls.py**

In the urlpattner of app I have

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),  # index view at /
    path('likePost/', views.likePost, name='likepost'),   # likepost view at /likepost
]
```

**views.py**

```
def likePost(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        likedpost = Post.obejcts.get(pk=post_id) #getting the liked posts
        m = Like(post=likedpost) # Creating Like Object
        m.save()  # saving it to store in database
        return HttpResponse("Success!") # Sending an success response
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a GET")
```

In Debug I received the follow message error

```
Not Found: /likePost
[25/Feb/2020 16:12:17] "GET /likePost?post_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 2335
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are mixing up the two solutions I provided.  You are now passing `post_id` as a **path parameter**, but are expecting it to come to your view as a **querystring** variable.  Please read carefully, and if it still doesn't make sense, let me know and I will try to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for help me @ReinstateMonica, but the error persists. I tried 2 options that you give me. but no sucess

Comment: Ok, It's right now. I used post_id as a querystring. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax script, you are passing a *querystring* parameter called **`post_id`** (eg. `likePost/?post_id=1`), but in your urlpatterns, you specify **`post_id`** as a *path parameter* (eg. `likePost/1/`).

You have 2 options:

### post_id as a *path parameter*

Add the **`post_id`** to the url instead of sending it as data:

```
$('.likebutton').click(function() {
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",

        // standard syntax
        url: "/likePost/" + catid,

        // template string syntax
        // url: `/likePost/${catid}`,

        success: function(data) {
            $('#like' + catid).remove();
            $('#message').text(data);
        }
    })
});
```

Then add **`post_id`** to your view:

```
def likePost(request, post_id):
    ...
```

### post_id as a *querystring*

change your path to the following:

```
path('likePost/', views.likePost, name='likepost')
```

You can then access **`post_id`** via `request.GET` in your view:

```
def likePost(request):
    post_id = request.GET['post_id']
    ...
```

Furthermore, I'd recommend reading [When do I use path parameters vs. query params in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api) if you aren't sure of which option to use.

Comment: I change my Ajax as you suggest. Now I received the follow error:
Not Found: /likepost/${catid}
[25/Feb/2020 16:47:58] "GET /likepost/$%7Bcatid%7D?post_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 2346

Comment: @RafaelChristófano it looks like you used double quotes eg. `"/likePost/${catid}"` instead of backticks

Comment: @RafaelChristófano I've modified my answer so that is doesn't use the *template string* syntax.  See the update

Comment: Also, if you aren't sure what I'm talking about, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: Not works yet
Not Found: /likePost/1
[25/Feb/2020 16:58:45] "GET /likePost/1 HTTP/1.1" 404 2311

Comment: @RafaelChristófano can you add an update with what you've changed exactly?