# C# How to send List as a param in url in mvc restapi?

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, .net-core, rest

I am looking for answer for this question for a lot of time, but I don't always get what I want.

This is the code in my REST controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Route("InsertOneProduct/{ean:long}/{name}/{producer}/{type}/{quantity:int}/{price:float}/{vat:int}")]
[HttpPost]
public void InsertOneProductWithType(long ean, string name, string producer, List<TypeOfProduct> type ,int quantity, float price, int vat)
{
     var product = new Products(ean, name, producer, type ,quantity, price, vat);

     mongoDB.InsertProducts(product);
}
```

This what I want is to send List of types in url, so i try to do this this way and many more but this doesn't work

```
https://localhost:44385/api/Rest/InsertOneProduct/059013590036/TyskieGronie/KompaniaPiwowarska/type=Tyskie/100/1.99/23

https://localhost:44385/api/Rest/InsertOneProduct/059013590036/TyskieGronie/KompaniaPiwowarska/Tyskie/100/1.99/23

https://localhost:44385/api/Rest/InsertOneProduct/059013590036/TyskieGronie/KompaniaPiwowarska/type="Tyskie"/100/1.99/23

https://localhost:44385/api/Rest/InsertOneProduct/059013590036/TyskieGronie/KompaniaPiwowarska/"Tyskie"/100/1.99/23`
```

Code of products and type of products:

```
public class Products
{
    [BsonId]
    ObjectId objectId { get; set; }
    public long ean { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string producer { get; set; }

    public List<TypeOfProduct> type { get; set; }
    public float price { get; set; }
    public int vat { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class TypeOfProduct
{
    string type;
}
```

Can somebody explain how to do it properly? Thanks for all answers

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create data on this route. Have you considered using a POST request instead? You could use a JSON (or other format) body with an array parameter to pass the multiple types through.

Comment: In general, I'm also questioning your choice to use so many path parameters instead of more query parameters. Types are resource properties, not resource identifiers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api) for more on that topic. Since path parameters are usually not compound data, you could try passing that in as URL option parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do exactly what you asking.
But you can do something like this:

1) Remove {type} from route string:
"InsertOneProduct/{ean:long}/{name}/{producer}/{type}/{quantity:int}/{price:float}/{vat:int}"

2) Add attribute [FromQuery] to 'type' parameter

3) Make field 'type' of class TypeOfProduct public and make it as property (add {get;set;})

result code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

  [Route("InsertOneProduct/{ean:long}/{name}/{producer}/{quantity:int}/{price:float}/{vat:int}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void InsertOneProductWithType(long ean, string name, string producer, [FromQuery]List<TypeOfProduct> type ,int quantity, float price, int vat)
    {
        var product = new Products(ean, name, producer, type ,quantity, price, vat);

        mongoDB.InsertProducts(product);
    }
```

Request example:

```
https://localhost:44385/api/Rest/InsertOneProduct/059013590036/TyskieGronie/KompaniaPiwowarska/"Tyskie"/100/1.99/23?type[0].type=asd&type[1].type=asdasdas
```

Tested on netcoreapp2.2 application

Comment: Hi! Thanks you for answer, i did what you say but it didn't work, values of List<TypeOfProduct> type is empty when i send the request.
Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Try to make field 'type' of TypeOfProduct as property (add {get;set;})

Comment: I feel now a little stupid, how a can forget about get and set...
Thank you again it works!