# Provide multiple path parameters to API Gateway (serverless)

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have a method **"DB_Update"** in a module.

This method requires **several Parameters as Input** (InputA, InputB and InputC)

```
module.exports.DB_Update = async (event) => 
{

    //extract Parameters from event
    InputA= event.pathParameters.InputA
    InputB= event.pathParameters.InputB
    InputC= event.pathParameters.InputC
   
    // Update Items in DB based on Input
    //...
}
```

I would like to invoke the function via an API request using **serverless** and **AWS API Gateway**

Hence in my **serverless yml file** I have added the function

```
DB_Update:
    handler: ../DB_Update
    events:
      - http:
          path: DB_Update/{InputA, InputB, InputB}
          method: get
```

and finally I **invoke the endpoint** via Postman using the parameters

```
http://localhost:3000/dev/DB_Update/InputA=9783404163809&InputB=111&InputC=BB
```

However regardless of which alternation I try I don't get it to work. Either yml does not accept the combination of Input Parameters or I dont get an event object back.

Hence it would be great if you could give me a **hint how to make this work**. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decide if you want to pass the parameters as Path Parameters (e.g. `baseurl/{varA}/{varB}/{varC}`) or Query Parameters (e.g. `baseurl?varA=x&varB=y&varC=z`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api#:%7E:text=Best%20practice%20for%20RESTful%20API,to%20sort%2Ffilter%20those%20resources.) provides some more insight into the different patterns.

Depending on which pattern you decide, request parameters should be included in the `serverless.yml` file in the following format (set fields to `true` if they're required, `false` if optional):

**Path Parameters**

```
DB_Update:
    handler: ../DB_Update
    events:
      - http:
          path: DB_Update/{InputA}/{InputB}/{InputC}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                InputA: true
                InputB: true
                InputC: true
```

**Query Parameters:**

```
DB_Update:
    handler: ../DB_Update
    events:
      - http:
          path: DB_Update
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                InputA: true
                InputB: true
                InputC: true
```

Visit [this section](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-parameters) of the Serverless Framework documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a thorough look on your code as well as the recommended other sources. They were very helpful and I was able to fix my code

Answer (score 1):

Answer above answers great. Just one note that you actually don't have to specify parameters under request for path parameters. Something like that is enough:

```
DB_Update:
    handler: ../DB_Update
    events:
      - http:
          path: DB_Update/{InputA}/{InputB}/{InputC}
          method: get
```

Also you can mix path and query parameters, so you can have something like this:

```
    handler: ../DB_Update
    events:
      - http:
          path: DB_Update/{InputD}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                InputA: true
                InputB: true
                InputC: true
```