# How to get data from query string in Java Spring boot REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have a requirement to read data after '?' in service-url in Spring boot REST API.

For example, We exposed a service called sampleService and GET URL for this is

http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce

And clients will pass the data as http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?dynamicdata

So we have to read that "dynamicdata" in my sample service and process.

Please let me know the possibilities.

Comment: What problem are you having doing this?

Comment: @tgdavies, As we are not mentioning any parameter (i mean key value pair), How to read that data ("dynamicdata")?

Comment: What is the content of dynamicdata? And why aren't you using key value pairs?

Comment: Actually this request is coming from a device. 
And they are going to prepare the URL like this. http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?<dynamicdata>

Example http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?$999900&124434&234*

Answer (score 3):

GET: **http://localhost:8080/api/foos?id=abc** here the query string is *id=abc* . Now to extract the value of id, you can use the code something like this.

```
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String id) {
    return "ID: " + id;
}
```

GET: **http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?dynamicdata** is incorrect. Either it should be **http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce/dynamicdata** (PathVariable) or **http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?title=dynamicdata** (RequestParam)

GET: **http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce/dynamicdata** to extract *dynamicdata*, you can use code something like

```
@GetMapping("/api/sampleServce/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public String getFooById(@PathVariable String id) {
    return "ID: " + id; // here id = "dynamicdata"
}
```

GET: **http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?title=dynamicdata** to extract *title*, you can use code something like

```
@GetMapping("/api/sampleServce")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String title) { 
    return "title: " + title; // title="dynamicdata"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dynamicdata` is path param, it cannot be placed after `?`. It should be something like this:

http://www.myservices.com/api/dynamicdata/sampleServce

Check [when and how to use query or path parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: Actually this request is coming from a device. And they are going to prepare the URL like this. 

http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?<dynamicdata>

Comment: You can't do this. This is an invalid  REST request.

Answer (score 0):

**Accept dynamic data through request param:**

```
@GetMapping("/api/sampleServce")
public void test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> dynamicdata) {
    System.out.println(dynamicdata.keySet()); //http://localhost:9001/dag-backend/api/sampleServce?test&test11

    Optional<String> data = dynamicdata.keySet().stream().findFirst();
    String value = data.isPresent() ? data.get() : null;
    System.out.println(value); //http://localhost:9001/dag-backend/api/sampleServce?test
}
```

URLs:

`http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?dynamicdata`
`http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?dynamicdata&12344&1212`
`http://www.myservices.com/api/sampleServce?$999900&124434&234`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an HttpServletRequest object to your mapped method signature:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/sampleServce")
public Object sampleServce (HttpServletRequest request) {
    //print everything after the question mark: 
    System.out.println("queryString: " + request.getQueryString());
    
    //print key value pairs: 
    Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
    while(params.hasMoreElements()){
        String paramName = params.nextElement();
        String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
        System.out.println("name: " + paramName);
        System.out.println("value: " + paramValue);
    }
    return request.getQueryString();
}
```