# Difference between API header and ulr path

Tags: api

What's the difference between the following 2?
/customers/{customerId}
and
/customers?id={customerId}
?

Which one is better?
Which one is more secure?

Comment: First one is a path parameter, second one a query parameter. See for example [When do I use path params vs. query params in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I use path params vs. query params in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: Thanks. That's a great summary. I'm new to stackoverflow. How can I mark your answer as the solution?