# Passing query parameter in nodejs but route is giving error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I want to pass the query parameter in the route. I used authentication middleware.

I want to delete a task based on that task id. Later I want to pass auth into delete by id route and allow the user to delete a task by authentication, but when I pass the query parameter the endpoint fails. If no query parameter is passed everything works fine.

**task.js**

```
const express = require('express')
require('../mongoose')
const Task = require('../model/task_model')
const auth = require('../middleware/user_middleware')
const router = new express.Router()

router.delete('/tasks/del/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const task = await Task.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)

        if (!task) {
            res.status(404).send()
        }

        res.send(task)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const UserRouter = require('./router/user')
const TaskRouter = require('./router/task')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(UserRouter)
app.use(TaskRouter)

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('Server listening on port: ' + port)
})
```

**middleware.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User = require("../model/user_model")

const auth = async function(req,res,next){
    try {
        const token = (req.headers.authorization).split(' ')[1]
        const decoded_token = jwt.verify(token,'ankan123')
        const user = await User.findOne({_id:decoded_token._id,"tokens.token":token})
        if (!user){
            throw new Error()
        } 
        req.user = user
        req.token = token
        next()
    } catch(e){
        res.status(400).send("PLease Authenticate")
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

**task_model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    task: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
    },
    completed:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    creator:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required:true
    }

})

const tasks = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema)

module.exports = tasks
```

**user.js**

```
const express = require('express')
require('../mongoose')
const User = require('../model/user_model')
const auth = require('../middleware/user_middleware')
const router = new express.Router()
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.matchCred(req.body.mobileNo, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateToken(user._id)
        return res.status(200).send({
            user,
            token
        })
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting route containing **/tasks/del/:id** does not exist when using postman to send delete requests.
[image: Postman Request]

[image: Mongodb task Collection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple you are passing it as query parameters, but it is path parameters. You can run like this in the postman:

```
{url}/tasks/del/'yourID'
```

When you pass id as query parameters, it won't be able to match the path and hence you are receiving an error `Can't Delete`. I would say you should understand diff b/w them and you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api) link.