# Django: Passing parameters in URL as query arguments

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

How can I pass parameters via URL as query parameters to avoid multiple and complicated url patterns?

For example, instead of making a complicated url like
`example.com/page/12/red/dog/japan/spot`
or something like that, and then a corresponding entry in urls.py that will parse that url and direct it to a view, I want to simply get a url where I can freely add or remove parameters as needed similar to the ugly way
`example.com/page?id=12&color=red&animal=dog&country=Japan&name=spot`

Then in **urls.py** simply have something like

```
path('page/<parameter_dictionary>', views.page, name='page' parameters='parameter_dictionary)
```

If I have to use url patterns, how can I account for urls that have parameters that may or may not fit the pattern, such as sometimes

```
"/page/12/red/dog/Japan/spot" -> path('page/<int:id>/<str:color>/<str:animal>/<str:country>/<str:name>', views.page, name='page'),
"/page/12/dog/red/Japan/"-> path('page/<int:id>/<str:animal>/<str:color>/<str:country>', views.page, name='page')
"/page/dog/red/Japan/"-> path('page/<str:animal>/<str:color>/<str:country>', views.page, name='page')
```

I would like to just have **anything** sent to `http://example.com/page/`
go to views.page(), and then be accessible by something like

```
animal = request.GET['animal']
color = request.GET['color']
id = request.GET['id']
```

etc. so examples below would all work via one entry in urls.py

```
example.com/page?id=12&animal=dog&country=Japan&name=spot 
example.com/page?id=12&color=red&animal=dog&name=spot
example.com/page?id=12&country=Japan&color=red&animal=dog&name=spot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for queryparameters and you are almost done with it. The following code is untested but should kinda work:

```
def page(request):
    animal = request.GET.get("animal",None) # default None if not present
    color = request.GET.get("color",None)
    return render(request,'some_html.html')
# urls.py:
path('page/', views.page, name='page')
```

You access the queryparameters via the passed request object `request.GET`. This is a dict like object. The main difference is that this object handles multi keys.

For example if you pass the these params `?a=1&a=2` to your url, it converts `request.GET.getlist("a") # Returns ["1","2"]` to a list.
`request.GET.get("a")` returns the last passed value `"2"` as @Kbeen mentioned in comments,. Read more about QueryDict [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict)

Also be sure to know the difference and best practice for url parameters and queryparameters. [Example Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Edit: Added `request.GET.getlist()`

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if you create and populate a Querydict, then it will generate a correctly encoded querystring for you to use in (say) a redirect. `querystring = querydict.urlencode()`. And of course request.GET is a populated Querydict if you want to pass a querystring from one view to the next.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!
I never even thought to actually just try to send it via "?a=this&b=that" because I never came across any example of that being done in my searches. 

I am new to Python after a fifteen year break from programming where I used Perl and PHP exclusively.  I thought maybe the ugly urls had been done away with when I was gone.

Comment: Just an edit to the jmangold's answer

 "for example if you pass the these params ?a=1&a=2 to your url, it converts `request.GET.get("a") # Returns ["1","2"].`"

That was just returning the last value in the list.

To get the full list it should be 
`request.GET.getlist("a") # Returns ["1","2"]`