# Having an issue with Next 13 app API Router issue 404

Tags: next.js

I have created an app to check out the new Next 13 changes. I have this service, which I call to call an API route.

```js
interface DrawCardsProps {
  deck_id: string;
}

export async function drawCards(deck_id: DrawCardsProps) {
  console.log("triggered", deck_id);
  const response = await fetch(`/api/draw-cards/${deck_id}`, {
    method: "GET",
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Status ${response.status} - Error Getting Shuffled Cards`);
  }

  return await response.json();
}
```

The API

```js
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { ZodError, z } from "zod";

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
  console.log(req.query, "TRIGGERED");
  const querySchema = z.object({
    deck_id: z.string(),
  });

  const deck = querySchema.parse(req.query.deck_id);

  console.log(deck, "deciID");
  try {
    const shuffledDeck = await fetch(
      `https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deck}/draw/?count=2`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    );
    if (shuffledDeck.ok) {
      return NextResponse.json(shuffledDeck);
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: "Failed Getting Deck" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(req.body, "bruh");
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

The API Route is under `app/api/draw-cards/route.ts`. I keep getting a 404 not found. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you accessing the api?

Comment: @darrenz Sorry I do not understand? I call the service with  const deckofCards = await drawCards(deck_id); then the service is an intermediary for the API route

Comment: make ur route like so app/api/draw-cards/[deck_id]/route.ts

Comment: Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/api/draw-cards/ez2g0gw9fbxo
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Remote Address:
[::1]:3000
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: or if you want to keep it u can access /api/draw-cards?deck_id=poop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to ping the api route via its params, but the code looks like you want to pass it as a query.

If you want to keep the params format, just change the folder structure
Here is the folder structure for params format:

```
app/api/draw-cards/[deck_id]/route.ts
```

If you want to have query format, do :

```
fetch ("/api/draw-cards?deck_id=poop")
```

[More info on query and params.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967822/when-do-i-use-path-params-vs-query-params-in-a-restful-api)

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems like I was mixing my approaches. The whole App router thing has thrown me off. Much appreciated.