# Good URL syntax for a GET request with a composite key

Tags: rest, url

Let's take the following resource in my REST API:

```
GET `http://api/v1/user/users/{id}`
```

In normal circumstances I would use this like so:

```
GET `http://api/v1/user/users/aabc`
```

Where `aabc` is the user id.

There are times, however, when I have had to design my REST API in a way that some extra information is passed with the ID. For example:

```
GET `http://api/v1/user/users/customer:1`
```

Where `customer:1` denotes I am using an id from the customer domain to lookup the user and that id is 1.

I now have a scenario where the identifier is more than one key (a composite key). For example:

```
GET `http://api/v1/user/users/customer:1;type:agent`
```

My question: in the above URL, what should I use as the separator between `customer:1` and `type:agent`?

According to https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt I believe that the semi-colon is not allowed.

Comment: Why not use query parameters, e.g. `/v1/users?customerId=1&type=agent`. `/user/users` seems suspicious, and making up your own representation is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Try to encode your URL.

Comment: I was thinking about it and I think this question is more in regards to what to do when your resource id is a composite key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a general structure for accessing records via multiple keys at once, I would suggest trying to think of this on more of a case-by-case basis.

To take your example, one way to interpret it is that you have multiple customers, and those customers each may have multiple user accounts. A natural hierarchy for this would be:

```
/customer/x/user/y
```

Often an elegant decision like this can be made, that not only solves the problem but also documents your data-model in a way that someone can easily see that users belong to customers via a 1-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You should either:

Use parameters:
GET `http://api/v1/user/users?customer=1`

Or use a new URL:
GET `http://api/v1/user/users/customer/1`

But use Standards like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3198507/9492380)

("Paths tend to be cached, parameters tend to not be, as a general rule.")